# Show progress animation using svg images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

[image: two images]

I tried with overlapping and increasing width of another but as they are not linear or simple like a rectangle .

[image: by overlapping into divs i m getting this but it isn't smooth]

I don't know if anyone have an idea to make progress bar out of these two images using html, css, js and these are svg files

Comment: draw them one on top of the other and animate a clip path to show the upper image gradually.

Answer (score 1):

Increase or decrease the width of the second div. Make sure the inner images are not `width:100%` or responsive

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="img1" style="position: absolute;top: 0;">
        <img src="amplitude.svg">
    </div>
    <div id="img2" style="position: absolute;top: 0;width: 20%;overflow: hidden;">
        <img src="amplitude-progress.svg">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```